Does Newton's forward difference formula / Newton's interpolation formula yield well-defined functions (in one variable) if it is convergent?
Suppose we are given a sequence $a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots$ of real numbers and we define $F:\mathbb{N}\times[0, \infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$ F(k, \alpha) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^{\underline{n}}}{n!} \Delta^{n} a_{k} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{\alpha}{n} \Delta^{n} a_{k} $$
where $\Delta a_{k} = a_{k+1} - a_{k}$, $\Delta^{2} a_{k} = a_{k+2} - 2a_{k+1} + a_{k}$, etc.
Suppose further the formula converges for all $k, \alpha$. Do we necessarily have the desirable property that
$$ F(k, \alpha) = F(0, k+\alpha)? $$
Is there a sequence $a_n$ for which $F$ is well-defined but it does not have the property (so we can't define $f(k+\alpha) = F(k, \alpha)$ unambiguously)?

Have you tried defining the $n$th order difference as a finite sum?

Let's consider the case of $k=1$. First, let's manipulate $F(1,\alpha)$:
$$F(1,\alpha)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}\Delta^{n}a_1=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}(\Delta^{n}a_0+\Delta^{n+1}a_0)=F(0,\alpha)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}\Delta^{n+1}a_0=F(0,\alpha)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n-1}\Delta^{n}a_0=F(0,\alpha)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}\frac{n}{\alpha-n+1}\Delta^{n}a_0$$
Then, let's manipulate $F(0,\alpha+1)$
$$F(0,\alpha+1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha+1}{n}\Delta^{n}a_0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha-n+1}\Delta^{n}a_0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}(1+\frac{n}{\alpha-n+1})\Delta^{n}a_0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}(\Delta^{n}a_0+\frac{n}{\alpha-n+1}\Delta^{n}a_0)=F(0,\alpha)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}\frac{n}{\alpha-n+1}\Delta^{n}a_0$$
So we basically got the same result. The fact that the remaining sum in the first result starts from $1$ and in the second from $0$ doesn't matter because the term for $n=0$ is equal to $0$ because of the $n$ in the numerator. Then I think you can prove this for arbitrary $k$ with induction.

Yes, $F(k,\alpha)=F(0,k+\alpha)$.
Hint 1. Consider the shift operator $(Sf)(n)=f(n+1)$. Observe $(S^kf)(n)=f(k+n)$. Writing $I$ for the identity operator $(If)(n)=f(n)$, we have $S=\Delta+I$, so by the binomial theorem,
$$ S^k ~=~ \sum_{s=0}^k\binom{k}{s}\Delta^s \tag{$\ast$}$$
Hint 2. Vandermonde convolution applies even if $\alpha$ is not an integer:
$$ \binom{\alpha+k}{n}=\sum_{r+s=n}\binom{\alpha}{r}\binom{k}{s} \tag{$\circ$}$$
Indeed, if we treat $\binom{\alpha}{n}$ as a function of integer $\alpha$ and apply $(\ast)$ we get $(\circ)$; since both sides are polynomials in $\alpha$ equal at all integers, an infinite number of values, they must be identical.
Can you put these two hints together?

This helped a lot, but I ran into a manipulation wherein I had to interchange the order of summations: $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{r=0}^{n} (\cdots) = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=r}^{\infty} (\cdots). $$ It's not clear this can work if the formula doesn't exhibit absolute convergence. (Perhaps you didn't need to interchange sums or you have a justification.)

@MaximusIdeal Can't you just take $k=1$ and then use induction to prove it for arbitrary $k$? Then there wouldn't be a double sum. That's what I did in my answer.
